# How do I create an order in which my images appear? (a MySQL+PHP question)

Tags: php, mysql

Right now, all my images are basically inserted onto my page at the same time (or so it appears). How can I create an order, so my images appear one being one left, left to right, top to bottom?

I'm using MySQL to store the image name by the way. So maybe I should create an order by ascending ID for which the image name is processed onto my php? I don't know, any recommendations would be appreciated.

This is a small bit of the code to illustrate what I mean. It's the image code being looped:

```
echo '<img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/pictures/' . $objResult["Image"] . '.png" />
```

EDIT:
Here's the code for more context:

```
<html>
<body>
    <?php
        $objConnect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
        $objDB = mysql_select_db("dfvdfv");
        $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM images";
        if (!isset($_GET['Page']))  $_GET['Page']='0';
        $objQuery = mysql_query($strSQL);
        $Num_Rows = mysql_num_rows($objQuery);
        $Per_Page = 16;   // Per Page
        $Page = $_GET["Page"];
        if(!$_GET["Page"])
        {
            $Page=1;
        }
        $Prev_Page = $Page-1;
        $Next_Page = $Page+1;
        $Page_Start = (($Per_Page*$Page)-$Per_Page);
        if($Num_Rows<=$Per_Page)
        {
            $Num_Pages =1;
        }
        else if(($Num_Rows % $Per_Page)==0)
        {
            $Num_Pages =($Num_Rows/$Per_Page) ;
        }
        else
        {
            $Num_Pages =($Num_Rows/$Per_Page)+1;
            $Num_Pages = (int)$Num_Pages;
        }

        $strSQL .=" order  by ImagesID ASC LIMIT $Page_Start , $Per_Page";
        $objQuery  = mysql_query($strSQL);
$cell = 0;
echo '<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="1"><tr>';
while($objResult = mysql_fetch_array($objQuery))
{
  if($cell % 4 == 0) {
    echo '</tr><tr>';
  }

if($cell == 2) {
    echo '<td>RESERVED</td>';
} elseif ($cell == 3) {
    echo '<td>The other cell</td>';
} else {
    echo '
    <td><img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/images/' . $objResult["Image"] . '" />' .
    $objResult["ImagesName"] . '</td>'; }
    $cell++;
}
echo '</tr></table>';
    ?>

        <br />
view more:
<?php
        if($Prev_Page)
        {
            echo " <a href='$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?Page=$Prev_Page'>prev</a> ";
        }
            {
                echo "|";
        }
        if($Page!=$Num_Pages)
        {
            echo " <a href ='$_SERVER[SCRIPT_NAME]?Page=$Next_Page'>next</a> ";
        }
        ?>
<?php
mysql_close($objConnect);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I still don't understand completely what you like to achieve: do you like to show your images in rows and columns?

Comment: left to right, top to bottom. I don't understand what you don't get..

Comment: @user - is the issue that they appear in some undefined order or that you don't know how to get them positioned on the page?

Comment: So in what order do you like your images being displayed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your iterating through a single loop to write your html and therefor the images it could be easily done by setting the css float attribute to left, put the images in a div container with a size of your choice, so the images row will break if they reach the right border. This will lead to building up the images from left to right.

A code example with your snippet embedded:

```
// open container
echo '<div style="width:\'500px\'">';

foreach ($results as $key => $objResult) {
    echo '<img style="float:left;" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/pictures/' . $objResult["Picture"] . '.png" />';
}
// close container
echo '</div>';
```

I suggest using stylesheet instead of setting the style attribute directly but for simplicity of the example it's just this way.

**example for second question in comments**

```
if ($objResult["description"]) {
    $imageTitle = $objResult["description"];
} else {        
    $imageTitle = $objResult["number"];
}       
echo 
    '<td>'.
        '<img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/images/' . $objResult["Image"] . '" />' .
        $imageTitle . 
    '</td>';
```

Comment: I just edited in my code for more context. Does your code snippet still apply?

Comment: No it doesn't cause your example is using a table, and it looks like you are already doing well with putting your images in rows and columnes.

Comment: So it's my eyes that are deceiving me right? I don't mean this in contempt/passivity, as my internet loading speed (for images) is pretty fast. Is that the case or is there another reason? Also, another question before giving you the checkmark, is it possible to create a column that allows you to enter in strings/letters and spaces, but also can autoincrement if nothing is entered into that column? Much thanks.

Comment: Are you referring to the phenomenon that some images are displayed earlier than other and not in the right order? Please open up another question for the second part with more context it's quite difficult to glue it all together.

Comment: Hah, I'm not sure if phenomen is used sarcasm or as a euphemism, but yes =p. In any case that doesn't really matter. And I don't know if I can explain the second part much clearer. I'm just wondering if there's a way to create a column which autoincrements, unless you enter in a string. Example. The column records go 1,2,3,4,5,etc. However, if I want I can rename 4 to 'buttersflies are cool'. In any case, all records I enter in will default to the autoincremented numbered. So the record after 'butterflies are cool' would be 5, if I choose not to put in any value.

Comment: I would do this using two columns, first one is of type int/decimal for ordering with numbers and the second one of type string/text. The first one autoincrements as normal, the second one only reflects a differing name. So if you find something the second column don't display the 4.

Comment: Whoa, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: In your db, add two columns to your images table as described above. Set the first one to autoincrement. Your query to get your images from your db will give you the two new columns. After that you can just check with php if there is something in the second column, if yes echo that, if no just echo the number of the first field.

Comment: Yeah that's what I don't get. Can you give me a sample echo code describing that?

Comment: Have a look at the my edited answer. It's a part of your code, which replaces the part after `if($cell == 2) {
    echo '<td>RESERVED</td>';
} elseif ($cell == 3) {
    echo '<td>The other cell</td>';
} else {
` It assumes that your db has two fields with the name number and description.

Comment: So pretty much the way for my php code to use else statement is if I declare the record in my first column, the column with autoincrement, a null, correct?

Comment: If I get you right, I'd say vice versa: declare the desciption null and have always an autoincrementing decimal in the field number.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the order in which images appear, add a sort_order column to your database and put an index on it.  When you add pictures, increment the sort_order.  I prefer to increment by 10 so I have room to move images in-between others.

When you select from the database make sure you `ORDER BY sort_order`.

Comment: Can you answer this in easy, here's how you do it form? If it's too much of a hassle, can you suggest me a tutorial?

Comment: Could not be any clearer than that. And a new field "ordering", put numbers in it, sort by it.